# fast sampling in R

Tags: r

Is there a faster method for taking a random sub sample (without replacement), than the `base::sample` function?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can get a little bit of a speed-up by eliminating the base::sample function call:

```
> x<- rnorm(10000)
> system.time(for(i in 1:100000) x[.Internal(sample(10000L, 10L, FALSE, NULL))])
   user  system elapsed 
  2.873   0.017   2.851 
> system.time(for(i in 1:100000) sample(x,10))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.420   0.025   3.258
```

Depending on your problem there may be other more clever ways of speeding up your code. Think about ways to replace many small calls to sample with one big one.

Comment: +1 for suggesting that the problem might be lots of small calls to `sample`.

Comment: +1 replacing many calls with one  --  I needed to divide a 235,000,000 population into random sets of 150,000 each.  At first I tried sampling the sets individually, but that would've taken over a day, so I sampled only once:

population <- sample(population, length(population))

then chunked.  Done within a half hour.

Answer (score 4):

The `dqrng` package tackles faster sampling in R.
Here is one example & benchmark (note that I have updated these benchmarks to address Ralf's comment below):

```
library(dqrng)
library(bench)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(892)
dqset.seed(871)
m <- 1000
n <- 99999
all <- m * n
bm <- bench::mark(samp = sample(x = c(1, -1), size = all, replace = TRUE),
                  dqsamp = dqsample(x = c(1,-1), size = all, replace = TRUE),
                  dqrrademacher = dqrrademacher(n),
                  check = FALSE, 
                  iterations = 3)
bm
plot(bm) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

`dqrng` is a lot faster - note that the x axis is on a log-scale!

Here is a related blogpost: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/04/fast-sampling-support-in-dqrng/.

Comment: Holy cow! That is fast. As someone doing millions of sample() calls this just improved my quality of life enormously!

Thanks!

Comment: Nice. Two comments: 1) dqrng 0.3.1 supports dqrrademacher, which should be even faster in your case. 2) The OP asked for sampling w/o replacement. dqrng‘s advantage should be even larger there.

Answer (score 2):

no

I can get 10,000 samples in 3 ms on my laptop with replacement.  Without replacement I can get them in 5ms.  Drawing multiple times from 500 distributions it takes 66 ms.  How fast did you need it to be?

Comment: scale up to to 1e8-1e9 and you will see how badly it scales

Comment: It scales badly at 1e9 because you run into RAM issues. Also, keep in mind these answers are from 9 years ago. You should do your own testing on the very different version of R we have now.

Comment: my reflection about 1e8-1e9 is based on R 4.0.3 and R-devel, having plenty of ram memory